# How to Disable or remove code auto create Delivery Order when confirm Sale Order in Odoo?

Tags: python, xml, odoo

helo guys, do you all know how to disable or remove code which auto create delivery order when confirm sale order. I have looking for it, but I still haven't found

[image]

Comment: Please specify your Odoo version. It will be helpful for others to help you.

Comment: it looks like Odoo v12

Comment: You need to provide more detail about your use case. Why are you wanting to disable it? Are you wanting the delivery to be created at a later time or just not at all? Is this needed for all products or only in some cases?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have found the solution, just comment or remove run method in ProcurementGroup Class